# Why does my TimerTask keep running faster and faster?

Tags: java, swing, timer, project

The project was to make a Asciimation player. For the most part it works finally but when the asciimation is looping it keeps going faster and faster each loop. Anyone know why?

I know the code is not the best and there is probably many things wrong with it. I would like some help but please just don't say it sucks and do not help at all.

The project is due today in about 5 hours so some fast help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProjectTwo extends JPanel implements ActionListener{   

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JTextArea window;    
    private static JTextField input;
    private static JLabel inputHere;
    private static JButton play;
    private static JButton pause;       
    private static String fileName = "";
    private static String textLine;     
    private static boolean haveFrameSize = false;
    private static int equalCounter;
    private static int frameSize;
    private static int lineCounter = 1;
    private static int totalFrames;
    private static int counter = 1;     
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();
    private boolean run;


    //constructor creates and adds the window, label, screen, play, and pause buttons.
    ProjectTwo(){

        window = new JTextArea(20,50);
        window.setEditable(false);
        window.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));          
        inputHere = new JLabel("Enter file name:");
        input = new JTextField(10);

        play = new JButton("Play"); 
        play.addActionListener(this);

        pause = new JButton("Pause");
        pause.addActionListener(this);

        add(window);
        add(inputHere);
        add(input);

        add(play);
        add(pause);     
    }

    //creates the JFrame 
    public static void createAndShowGUI(){

        frame = new JFrame("AsciiMation");  
        //Create and set up the window.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);        
        frame.add(new ProjectTwo());    

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //main
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();            
            }
        });
    }

    //code for pressing the play and pause button
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //if the play button was pressed
        if (e.getSource() == play){
            //if there is something in the text box
            if (!input.getText().equals("")){
                run = true;
                //if the name is not the file that is already uploaded
                if(input.getText().equals(fileName)){

                }
                    fileName = input.getText();
                    getFrameSize();

                    int counter = 1;
                    //go to method that controls the animation
                    if(!input.getText().equals("File does not exist")){
                        asciimation movie = new asciimation(fileName, frameSize, totalFrames);
                        timer.schedule(new DrawAFrameTask(), 1, 50);                         

                }
              }         
            }        


        //if the pause button was pressed
        else{
             run = false;//if pause freeze the display on a frame until the Play button is clicked again
        }       
    }

    public void getFrameSize(){
        haveFrameSize = false;
        lineCounter = 1;
        frameSize = 0;
        totalFrames = 0;
        //import the file with the inputed name
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileName);
        //this is to get the size of the frame before sending it to be recorded into an array
        try{
            Scanner fileLine = new Scanner(file);

            while (fileLine.hasNextLine()){
                textLine = fileLine.nextLine();
                if(textLine.equals("=====") && haveFrameSize == false){
                    frameSize = lineCounter;
                    haveFrameSize = true;
                }
                lineCounter++;

                if(textLine.equals("=====")){
                    equalCounter++;
                }       
            }
            fileLine.close();

            totalFrames = equalCounter;

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException f){
            input.setText("File does not exist");   
        }
    }

    private class DrawAFrameTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {         
            asciimation movie = new asciimation(fileName, frameSize, totalFrames);      
            window.setText(movie.displayFrame(counter));
            counter++;
            timer.schedule(new DrawAFrameTask(), 1000, 1000);
            if(counter > totalFrames){
                counter = 1;
            }
        }

    }
}












    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class asciimation {
    private String[] movie;
    private String textLine;
    private String line;
    private String newLine = "\n";

    int frameSize = 0;


    public asciimation(String fileName, int frameSize, int totalFrames){

        movie = new String[totalFrames];
        for(int index = 0; index < totalFrames; index++){
            movie[index] = "";
        }

        //import the file with the inputed name
                java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileName);
                //this is to get the size of the frame before sending it to be recorded into an array

                try {
                    Scanner fileLine = new Scanner(file);

                    //while (fileLine.hasNextLine()){
                        //put each frame in the array
                        for (int array = 0; array < totalFrames-1; array++){                                                                            
                            //add each line of the frame and a /n to make the frame
                            for (int lineNum = 1; lineNum < frameSize; lineNum++){
                                if(fileLine.hasNextLine()){
                                    line = fileLine.nextLine();                                 
                                    movie[array] += ((line == null) ? "" : line) + newLine;                                 
                                }                                   
                            }
                            //skip lines that are "====="
                            if(fileLine.hasNextLine()){
                                line = fileLine.nextLine();
                            }
                        }                           
                    //}                                                 
                    fileLine.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException f){                        
                }
    }


    public String displayFrame(int frameNum){
        String frame = movie[frameNum-1];

        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to minimize the amount of code needed to reproduce the issue. In doing so you'll likely solve the problem yourself

Comment: 1. Yours is a Swing program and so you shouldn't even be using a java.util.Timer and TimerTask. 2. Instead use a javax.swing.Timer or "Swing" Timer. 3. Your code shows gross static modifier overuse, and you'll want to fix this, and instead make your code composed of OOPs compliant classes. If you're using static to fix a bug, then you're fixing it backwards. The solution is not to make things static but to change the code so that static is not needed.

Comment: 4. Fix your code formatting. Use consistent regular indentations. Avoid excess unnecessary or non-sense comments, have only one blank line, not multiple. Your goal is to post code that is easy to read and understand so that you'll get a good answer soon. Myself, I find it very difficult to read and understand your posted code, so I'll await improvements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I shortened your code. Please see below.
This part of code is what you need to understand.
You invoke timer.schedule(new Test(), 1, 50), which means you want to call Test.run every 50 ms repeatedly. So, what happens is that run() will be invoked every 50 ms and new timer will be created whenever run() is executed. That's why your timer goes faster (actually the individual timer's period is fixed, but you will have more and more timer whenever run() is executed)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test extends TimerTask {

    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        timer.schedule(new Test(), 1, 50); 
    }
    public void run() {         

        timer.schedule(new Test(), 1000, 1000);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    }

}
```

You can simply remove the second timer.schedule() to solve the problem. Please see below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test extends TimerTask {

    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        timer.schedule(new Test(), 1, 50); 
    }
    public void run() {         

        //timer.schedule(new Test(), 1000, 1000);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The whole timing aspect just keeps confusing the heck out of me. That's for answering my question

Comment: -1 for the propagation of violation of the single thread nature of Swing

Comment: @MaxHeap You don't have, the question is Swing oriented (it's even tagged as such), you've "answered" the question, but haven't "solved" the problem.  The approach the OP is taking is the wrong one for what they are trying to do. As professionals, we should not only help users understand their problems, but where applicable, provide guidance to more appropriate ways of achieving their goals

Answer (score 3):

First, if you take a look at the [JavaDocs for `java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) you will notice it says

> Schedules the specified task for **repeated** fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay

So what this basically means is, you are creating multiple times, which are ALL repeating at an interval ALL of which are updating the state of the UI...

Which leads into...Swing is a single threaded environment, mean that you should never block the Event Dispatching Thread with long running or block processes but, more importantly for you, Swing is NOT thread safe, meaning that you should NEVER update the UI from any thread OTHER then the Event Dispatching Thread.

So based on your example, you are violating the second rule of Swing - don't modify the UI from outside the context of the EDT.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) more details...

Now sure, you could use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to try and fix the problem, but a simpler solution which will resolve both of your issues would be to use a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of a `java.util.Timer`

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

For example...

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ProjectTwo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea window;
    private final JTextField input;
    private final JLabel inputHere;
    private final JButton play;
    private final JButton pause;
    private String fileName = "";
    private String textLine;
    private boolean haveFrameSize = false;
    private int equalCounter;
    private int frameSize;
    private int lineCounter = 1;
    private int totalFrames;
    private int counter = 1;
    private final Timer timer;
    private boolean run;

    private Asciimation movie;

    //constructor creates and adds the window, label, screen, play, and pause buttons.
    ProjectTwo() {

        window = new JTextArea(20, 50);
        window.setEditable(false);
        window.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        inputHere = new JLabel("Enter file name:");
        input = new JTextField(10);

        play = new JButton("Play");
        play.addActionListener(this);

        pause = new JButton("Pause");
        pause.addActionListener(this);

        add(window);
        add(inputHere);
        add(input);

        add(play);
        add(pause);

        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (movie != null) {
                    window.setText(movie.displayFrame(counter));
                    counter++;
                    if (counter > movie.frameSize) {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //main
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("AsciiMation");
                //Create and set up the window.
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ProjectTwo());

                //Display the window.
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    //code for pressing the play and pause button
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //if the play button was pressed
        if (e.getSource() == play) {
            //if there is something in the text box
            if (!input.getText().equals("")) {
                run = true;
                //if the name is not the file that is already uploaded
                if (input.getText().equals(fileName)) {

                }
                fileName = input.getText();
                getFrameSize();

                int counter = 0;
                //go to method that controls the animation
                if (!input.getText().equals("File does not exist")) {
                    movie = new Asciimation(fileName, frameSize, totalFrames);
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
        } //if the pause button was pressed
        else {
            run = false;//if pause freeze the display on a frame until the Play button is clicked again
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public void getFrameSize() {
        haveFrameSize = false;
        lineCounter = 1;
        frameSize = 0;
        totalFrames = 0;
        //import the file with the inputed name
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileName);
        //this is to get the size of the frame before sending it to be recorded into an array
        try {
            Scanner fileLine = new Scanner(file);

            while (fileLine.hasNextLine()) {
                textLine = fileLine.nextLine();
                if (textLine.equals("=====") && haveFrameSize == false) {
                    frameSize = lineCounter;
                    haveFrameSize = true;
                }
                lineCounter++;

                if (textLine.equals("=====")) {
                    equalCounter++;
                }
            }
            fileLine.close();

            totalFrames = equalCounter;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            input.setText("File does not exist");
        }
    }

    public class Asciimation {

        private String[] movie;
        private String textLine;
        private String line;
        private String newLine = "\n";

        int frameSize = 0;

        public Asciimation(String fileName, int frameSize, int totalFrames) {

            movie = new String[totalFrames];
            for (int index = 0; index < totalFrames; index++) {
                movie[index] = "";
            }

            //import the file with the inputed name
            java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileName);
            //this is to get the size of the frame before sending it to be recorded into an array

            try {
                Scanner fileLine = new Scanner(file);

            //while (fileLine.hasNextLine()){
                //put each frame in the array
                for (int array = 0; array < totalFrames - 1; array++) {
                    //add each line of the frame and a /n to make the frame
                    for (int lineNum = 1; lineNum < frameSize; lineNum++) {
                        if (fileLine.hasNextLine()) {
                            line = fileLine.nextLine();
                            movie[array] += ((line == null) ? "" : line) + newLine;
                        }
                    }
                    //skip lines that are "====="
                    if (fileLine.hasNextLine()) {
                        line = fileLine.nextLine();
                    }
                }
                //}                                                 
                fileLine.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            }
        }

        public String displayFrame(int frameNum) {
            String frame = movie[frameNum - 1];

            return frame;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I had the same program running twice without realizing it, which gave me notifications at faster rates. Dummy mistake.